# iOS - copy file after open in my app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

after clicked open in (pdf file) with this code:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
       openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
    annotation:(id)annotation {
if (url != nil && [url isFileURL]) {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSFileManager *filemgr;
    NSError *erf;
    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([filemgr copyItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", url] toPath:documentsDirectory error: &erf]  == YES)
        NSLog (@"Copy successful");
    else
        NSLog (@"Copy failed%@dest: %@", erf, url);
}
return YES;
```

}

I want copy file to my app but i have this error:

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)" UserInfo=0x200826c0 {NSFilePath=file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/*******.pdf, NSUnderlyingError=0x20082510 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}
>   Whi?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't convert an `NSURL` representing a file URL to an `NSString` using `stringWithFormat:`. You need to call the `path` method on the `NSURL`. And the `toPath:` parameter needs to be a full path including filename, not just the directory your want to copy to.

```
NSString *sourcePath = [url path];
NSString *destPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[url lastPathComponent]];

if ([filemgr copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destPath error:&erf]) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to think about moving that onto a background queue/thread because you are essentially locking up your app when it's called. This has two major side effects

1. Your app will appear to have hung during the copy operation, which will not be great for the user experience.
2. If it takes too long to do the copy, the app will not be able to respond to the OS and so the OS will think the app has hung forever and will kill it.

I would write a new method that takes a URL for copying and then you can do some unit testing against that method to make sure it's solid, before then scheduling it onto a queue/background thread in your application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: